# json array for one to many relations

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to create a json string from two table's queries in one to many relations. I have done like this

```
$query = "SELECT id,name FROM sample1 ORDER BY id ASC" ;                
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$parent = array() ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $parent[]= array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name']);
    $query1 = "SELECT id,cid,cmessage FROM sample2 WHERE id = '$row[id]' ORDER BY cid ASC" ;            
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $parent[] = array("id"=>$row1['id'],"cid"=>$row1['cid'],"comment"=>$row1['cmessage']);

    }  
} echo  json_encode($parent);
```

it shows an output like this `[{"id":"1","name":"Arathy"},{"id":"1","cid":"11","comment":"hai"},{"id":"1","cid":"111","comment":"exe"},{"id":"2","name":"Dhanya"},{"id":"2","cid":"22","comment":"yes"}]`

But I want the format like as shown below ,

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Arathy",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cid": "11",
            "comment": "hai"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "cid": "111",
            "comment": "exe"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Dhanya",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "cid": "22",
            "comment": "yes"
        }
    ]
} ]
```

Please help to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $parent[$row['id']]= array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name']);
    $query1 = "SELECT id,cid,cmessage FROM sample2 WHERE id = '$row[id]' ORDER BY cid ASC" ;            
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $parent[$row['id']]["details"][] = array("id"=>$row1['id'],"cid"=>$row1['cid'],"comment"=>$row1['cmessage']);

    }  
}
echo json_encode($parent);
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).